# Problems using $select with $expand in Priority REST API

Tags: priority-web-sdk

Using the Rest API, I'm trying to use $select with $expand like this:

```
https://priority.company.biz/odata/Priority/tabula.ini/company/DOCUMENTS_D?$filter=CURDATE ge 2020-01-01 and CURDATE le 2020-01-31&$expand=TRANSORDER_D_SUBFORM&$select=CUSTNAME,CDES
```

I get a 500 error. It seems that these two operators don't work together. I tried each one of them separately and they work. Any insights?

Answer (score 1):

from which programming lang do you call the rest service ?   It works Ok if you use the rest date format 
CURDATE eq 2020-04-28T00:00:00+00:00
when you call url with specical chars like + you must replace it for example + = %2B

from C# for example we use Uri.EscapeDataString(MyDateString) to combine the date in the URL

Answer (score 0):

try this:

subform needs to be in paranthesis
and no & before subform's select

```
https://priority.company.biz/odata/Priority/tabula.ini/company/DOCUMENTS_D?$select=DOCNO,TYPE,CUSTNAME, CDES&$filter=CURDATE ge 2020-01-01 and CURDATE le 2020-01-31&$expand=TRANSORDER_D_SUBFORM
```

Comment: what response you are getting?

Comment: By the way, I just fixed the syntax. Not the fields you refer to. But as far as I know, TRANSORDER_D doesnt have the fields CUSTNAME, CDES

Comment: I fixed it assuming your intention is to take CUSTNAME, and CDES from DOCUMENTS_D rather than TRANSORDER_D 
I've added also DOCNO, and TYPE as they are the key of the form, and therefore must be included in every call.
Hopes that helps

Comment: Apparently, the problem was that DOCNO and TYPE was missing. I did not see that in the documentation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When combining `$expand` and `$select` features you must include in the `$select` parameter the key(s) of the upper-level form.

Your corrected URL:

```
https://priority.company.biz/odata/Priority/tabula.ini/company/DOCUMENTS_D?$filter=CURDATE ge 2020-01-01 and CURDATE le 2020-01-31&$expand=TRANSORDER_D_SUBFORM&$select=CUSTNAME,CDES,DOCNO,TYPE
```

Priority software added it to its [documentation](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/restapi/query/#Combining_Query_Options) recently:

> Note: When using the $expand command for a subform with composite keys, the $select command must include all key fields from the upper-level form

And I add: It is not only for composite keys but for all simple 'one-column' keys.